# Creating Subnet Mask

Tags: networking, subnet

ive been set this task.

given the network 140.50.0.0/16

Create a subnet mask for 400 subnets with the maximum possible number of hosts in each subnet.

My question is how do i create a subnet mask??

Comment: a /16 has 65,536 hosts. You can break that down per interface on a router by assigning portion of that subnet for each interface. See this chart for assistance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks.  You could do a bunch of /25 subnets (126 usable host addresses each).

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the smallest power of 2 that's greater than 400, which is 512. That's 2<sup>9</sup>, so you need 9 bits in addition to the 16 bits in the original network mask. So the subnet mask is `255.255.255.128`. Each subnet will contain 128 addresses, of which 126 can be used for hosts (the first identifies the subnet itself, the last is the broadcast address).